# Best way to make a class auto-memoize

Tags: python, memoization

I've been working on developing a test framework (on top of Selenium and other tool sets, though that is not particularly relevant), and one of the components I decided would make it easier to extend the framework would be an easy way to add class members (for example, data elements that extract from the page in page objects) that auto-memoize.  The solution I came up with was a class that overrides `__getattr__()` that can be used as a parent class for every class that needs auto-memoize.  The code for this class follows:

```
class SelfCachingGetters(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        getter_string = '_get_%s' % name
        try:
            value = getattr(self, getter_string)()
            setattr(self, name, value)
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('%s is not a member of this class.' % name)
        return value
```

This class makes it so all you have to do to create an auto-memoizing member in any subclass is declare a method `_get_XXXX()` where XXXX is the name you want your class member to have.  I like this because it makes for a simple and clean way to implement this functionality, without having, for instance, dozens of methods with decorators in each page object.

My question is, is this the best (most Pythonic) way to implement this behavior?  Something about it seems very un-OO to me.  I was looking in to metaclasses and class decorators.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?